# Vue JS set computed value in a component

Tags: vue.js

How to change show computed property in mycomponentone, when clicking on the button "Click me child"? Currently, It does not work...

If I click on "Click me parent", it works, passed props to mycomponentone successfully updating

```js
Vue.component('mycomponentone', {
  props: {
    showText: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    show: {
      get() {
        return this.showText
      },
      set(value) {
        return value;
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showChild() {
      this.show = false
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{ show }} <br/><br/> <button @click="showChild()" >Click me child</button></div>'
})

Vue.component('mycomponenttwo', {
  data() {
    return {
      showTextParent: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showParent() {
      this.showTextParent = !this.showTextParent;
    }
  },
  template: '<div><button @click="showParent()" >Click me parent</button><mycomponentone v-bind:show-text="showTextParent" /></div>'
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <mycomponenttwo />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `emit`.

With emit you can call parent function inside child component.

And really I don't know what you want to do but here is an example:

```js
Vue.component('mycomponentone', { 
  props: {
    showText: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    show: {
      get() {
        return this.showText
      },
      set(value) {
        return value;
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showChild() {
       this.show = false
       this.$emit("changeShowText", true)
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{ show }} <br/><br/> <button @click="showChild" >Click me child</button></div>'
})

Vue.component('mycomponenttwo', { 
   data() {
    return {
      showTextParent: true
    }
   },
  methods: {
     showParent() {
       this.showTextParent = !this.showTextParent;
     },
     changeFromChild(status) {
     this.showTextParent = status
     }
  },
  template: '<div><button @click="showParent()" >Click me parent</button><mycomponentone @changeShowText="changeFromChild" v-bind:show-text="showTextParent" /></div>'
})


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 
<div id="app">
    <mycomponenttwo />
</div>
```